What is this usage of 流れが?

Upon receive the latest war news about the fact their army has started to recapture several territories, the character makes this comment.

戦いってのは流れがあるから

I'm not sure how to take it? "Things called battles have a flow"? Is it some way of saying?

I imagine looking down from a height observing the battle and seeing waves of men charging forward to engage the enemy.  From a height this might look like the army is flowing across the field of battle.

Sports commentators often use this word for what might be referred to as "momentum" in English.

First, "things called battle" does not seem to be a good translation to me. For this ってのは (or というのは, とは), please read this.
In your context, 流れ refers to some invisible force or momentum that influences the progression of events, either positively or negatively. It's thought to be hard for a human to control. For example:

彼のホームランで試合の悪い流れがひっくり返った。
His home run completely reversed the negative momentum.

If 戦いっていうのは流れがある ("Battles have their own flow") is a reaction to news about war, it may be implying "You won't always win or always lose because you can't go against the uncontrollable tide/momentum".

See entry #4 in goo:
時間の経過や物事の移り変わり。「時代の—に乗る」「試合の—を読む」
"The passage of time, or changes in things"
In English, the expression "ebb and flow" is similarly applied to things like war and politics.
Perhaps the general is pleasantly surprised that they are winning now, but he knows that things will eventually change again... and again.
